# How to reloadData after an in app purchase through modalView

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, tableview

I've looked at different sources to find an answer to this and possibly tried several ways to reloadData() but no luck so far.

Here is my case:

I have a tabBar where I present the content in a tableView. When you go into that tab, I present a modal view if you are not purchased the content yet.

[image]
Let's say you have purchased the content. The modal view dismisses itself but tableview doesn't show anything unless you kill the app and re-run again. When you this, tableView reloads itself with the content. No problem there. But this is definitely problematic and I do lose users just because of this.

I do keep track of the purchase with a key like this:

```
private var hiddenStatus: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey:"purchaseStatus")
```

I set it to true on a successful purchase as shown below:

```
self.setNonConsumablePurchase(true)
```

And finally the code where I check if the key is set to "true" on purchase. I call this on the viewDidLoad but it doesn't make sense because it's been already called when user touched on this tabBar item.

```
if hiddenStatus == true {

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

        self.segmentioView.valueDidChange = { [weak self] _, segmentIndex in

            switch self?.segmentioView.selectedSegmentioIndex {
            case 0:
                self?.observeAugustProducts()
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            case 1:
                self?.observeSeptemberProducts()
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            default:
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
 }
```

So I'm looking for two things:

1- To keep everything as it is and tweak the code to make this work.

2- Alternative ideas to give users a better in-app purchase experience (I once used UIAlertViewController for in-app purchase but decided not to go with it)

Comment: You can either use a notification, a delegate, or try to access the presentingViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using this extension:

```
extension NotificationCenter {
    func setUniqueObserver(_ observer: AnyObject, selector: Selector, name: NSNotification.Name, object: AnyObject?) {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer, name: name, object: object)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(observer, selector: selector, name: name, object: object)
    }
}
```

Before dismissing your Modal View, have your Modal View's ViewController post a Notification.

Something like:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: "Purchased", object: nil)
```

Then have your TableView's ViewController register to listen for that Notification (in **viewWillAppear**) - and handle it.

Something like:

```
NotificationCenter.default.setUniqueObserver(self, selector: #selector(handlePurchased), name: "Purchased", object: nil)
```

and

```
@objc func handlePurchased() {
    // Reload your TableView, etc.
}
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Thanks Jason. I was actually using notifications but not quite like this. It seems like I was missing out some points. It reloads the data successfully.